# get_post() with filters applied

Tags: filters, the-content, get-post

*** PLEASE SEE UPDATE BELOW AS THIS QUESTION IS EVOLVING ***

Is it possible to call `get_post()` and have the filters applied for the ID passed to the `get_post()` function?

My client has asked if we can pull content in from other custom posts when a visitor lands on a specific page - without updating the theme or adding extra pages.

Trying to get it working, I've written the following test function to modify `the_content` hook (please ignore the hardcoding as I'm trying to get the function working first...)

```php
    function wbp_the_content($content) {
        if (is_main_query()) {
            if (is_page('landing-page')) {
                remove_filter('the_content', 'wbp_the_content');
                
                $my_postid = 7699;//This is page id or post id
                $content_post = get_post($my_postid, OBJECT, 'display');
                $content = $content_post->post_content;
                $content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
                $content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content);
                $content .= get_the_id();
                add_filter( 'the_content', 'wbp_the_content', 10, 1);
            }
        }
        return $content;
    }
    
    add_filter( 'the_content', 'wbp_the_content', 10, 1);
```

It almost does what I want ... except... `apply_filters` is treating the data with the_id in the loop. Whereas I want it to apply the filters with the data relevant to, in this case, post 7699.

*** UPDATE ***

So, I found that by creating a loop, it works:

```php
function wbp_the_content($content) {
    if (is_main_query()) {
        if (is_singular('pc_landing_page') || is_page('landing-page')) {
            remove_filter('the_content', 'wbp_the_content');
            
            $my_postid = 7699;//This is page id or post id
            
            $custom_post = new WP_Query(['page_id' => '7699' ] );
            //var_dump($custom_post);
            if ($custom_post->have_posts()) {
                $custom_post->the_post();
                $content = apply_filters('the_content', get_the_content());
                $content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content);
                $content .= "zzzz". get_the_id() . " " . $my_postid;
            }
            wp_reset_postdata();
            
            add_filter( 'the_content', 'wbp_the_content', 10, 1);
        }
    }
    return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wbp_the_content', 10, 1);
```

But... I don't like it as is feels like creating a loop here is the wrong thing to do... and that there must be a better way of achieving what I'm looking to do.

What the client wants is to be able to send people to a page on their site - say `/landing-page` - and for it to show a default set of content.

However, if a user (paid for subscriber) on the site creates their own version of the page (a special custom post) and sends traffic to `/landing-page` with their ID (i.e. `/landing-page?id=7`) it should show their page and not the default page.

A cookie should be set at the same time so that if the visitor ever comes back (whilst the cookie is still there) they should see the bespoke variant of the landing page. Even though the theme is really bringing in the content from `/custom-page/freds-page`.

The key thing is we don't want to redirect to a different URL - whichever page content we show, the URL must be `/landing-page`. Just the content needs to magically change depending on the query var or if a cookie is set.

Any thoughts on a better way to do this would be most welcome.

Thank you,
Mark

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, but note that `the_id()` echo the post ID, so you'd want to use `get_the_ID()`. Also, `the_content` is a filter hook, so use `add_filter()` and not `add_action()`.

Comment: Thank you Sally - good feedback and have updated code and question. Though, I think I'm on the wrong path for doing what I want to do but not sure what's the right way as there's probably a nicer method of achieving this specific requirement...

Comment: I've re-read the question a few times, and while i understand the technical part, I still don't know what your client wants. The closest I can imagine is that these landing pages are posts with categories, and you want to show a list of posts in the same category at the end. Or, that you're trying to reinvent reusable blocks which let you take a handful of blocks and embed them across your site, and when you update them, they update everywhere

Comment: Hi Tom, thank you for asking the question.  

The client wants a default landing page that visitors see by default.

But if the visitor is directed to the site by a specific user (using a ?id=x), then the visitor should be shown the content from a page created by that user - and any time the visitor comes back, a cookie will be set so they continue to see that "bespoke page". 

I have found an answer to my own question which is I need to create a loop and that does what I want... but I don't like it as it feels wrong to create a loop in a filter....